# Pick one value from multiple values satisfying a condition

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
a = ['eddy', 'dyed', 'dye', 'dey', 'ed', 'ye', 'de']
```

Then the output should be:

```
new_list = ['eddy','dye','ed']
```

First element will always be taken (i.e. 'eddy') and then the length of the next element should be one less character than the previous element (in this case, length of 'dye' is one less character than that of 'eddy' and so on). I only need first element satisfying the condition. (no need of 'dey' even though it is satisfying the condition. Need only one element satisfying the condition)

There can be multiple ways to implement this but I can't seem to find a way to implement it correctly. Below is what I've tried so far.

```
a = ['eddy', 'dyed', 'dye', 'dey', 'ed', 'ye', 'de']
temp=[a[0]] #first element will always be taken
i=0

while i<len(a):
  if len(a[i]) == len(temp[0])-1: 
     temp.append(a[i])
  i+=1
```

This is giving me below output which is not correct:

```
['eddy', 'dye', 'dey']
```

@Mad Physicist: I provided below list:

```
    a=['abaca', 'baa', 'cab', 'aba', 'ab', 'ba', 'aa']
```

It gave me below output:

```
    ['abaca']
```

Comment: Originally a C programmer or similar?

Comment: Sort them by length, and then grab each one meeting a certain length.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds. That's O(nlogn). OP already has O(n) framework in place. It may be easier to read, but seems like overkill.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I've already sorted them. The problem is that there are multiple elements meeting a certain length. I only want to take the first element of those.

Comment: If it's not sorted how do you avoid multiple passes of some elements? If the elements are not sorted and you're grabbing them by some *order*...are you not sorting some of them? If each item has a distinct length, you *are* sorting them...not going to happen in *O(n)* in general.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds. Good point. I didn't really get that consideration from the question. But the point is moot since OP has already sorted the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem with your solution is that you are comparing with the length of the original element instead of the last appended one. To do that, you can use Python's handy negative indexing feature. Just change `if len(a[i]) == len(temp[0])-1:` to `if len(a[i]) == len(temp[-1])-1:`.

There is actually another problem, that your secondary dataset showcases. You only check if the next word is exactly one shorter than the previous, but you really want to check if it is any amount shorter. So really `if len(a[i]) == len(temp[0]) - 1:` should be `if len(a[i]) < len(temp[-1]):`.

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/eI46iu).

That being said, there are a number of other improvements you can make to your code. It is not very idiomatic to loop over arrays in Python using a `while` loop and an index counter, especially since you don't really care about the index at all. A better way would be to do something like

```
a = ['eddy', 'dyed', 'dye', 'dey', 'ed', 'ye', 'de']
temp=[a[0]] #first element will always be taken

for word in a:
  if len(word) < len(temp[-1]):
     temp.append(word)
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/KSDl9E).

And finally, this being Python, there has to be a one line solution to something like this, as a matter of course. In this case, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a `key` of [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['eddy', 'dyed', 'dye', 'dey', 'ed', 'ye', 'de']

temp = [next(group) for key, group in groupby(a, len)]
```

Here is an [IDEOne link](https://ideone.com/fF2Tp1).

Comment: This worked for this particular list but when I change the list, it's giving me different output.

Comment: @ShadowFiend. Could you show an example by editing the question?

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem. You skip a length. Will fix momentarily. My last one-liner solution should work as-is BTW.

Comment: Mad Physicist - It's giving an error "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not an iterator"

Comment: @ShadowFiend. I see one sec. Fixed the other ones in the meantime.

Comment: @ShadowFiend. Fixed. I fogot about the first output of `groupby` which is the key. Stupid mistake, especially since I skimmed the docs when I linked them :)

Comment: Mad Physicist- That worked. Thank you for your efforts. That was useful!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in your if statement, it's always checking against the length of the first element, not the new 'length' that it should be using. Thus, you keep grabbing elements of length 3.

```
newIndex = 0
while i < len(a):
  if len(a[i]) == len(temp[newIndex])-1: 
     temp.append(a[i])
     newIndex = i
  i+=1
```

Try that out.

Comment: need to initialize 'i' in while loop

Comment: ah yeah, i was just putting the blocks of code that needed to be changed